# How to use Avisynth+AvsP with VirtualDub frame server?

Tags: virtualdub

I'm trying to improve some VHS-C home video recordings for my mother. I used `VirtualDub` to capture the recordings as avi files and now I wish to modify them with `Avisynth` but I can't get the frame server function to work. Has anyone got the `VirtualDub` frame server connection with `Avisynth` working in Windows 10?

I've tried this with the latest versions of `VirtualDub`, `Avisynth`, and both `AvsP_v2.0.2` with `bugfix3` and `AvsPmod`. Also, I've tried it with `VirtualDub_1910.exe`, `Avisynth_258.exe`, `AVSPluginPack.exe` and `AvsPmod_205.exe` from AnimeMusicVideos.org (`AMVapp31.zip`). I'm using Windows 10 64-bit however I've only downloaded 32-bit version software and codecs because that seems to be the generally recommended route. (Is the `AVSPluginPack` necessary? If so, is there somewhere other than AMV that maintains it?)

In VirtualDub, I open `homevideo.avi`, "Crop to selection" for a desired range of frames and then `File > Start frame server...` and name the Avi-File Handler `video.vdr`.

In AvsP and AvsPmod the commands:

```
video = AVISource("c:\VHSC\video.avs")
return video
```

where `video.avs` is a file that contains only the line `AviSource("c:\VHSC\video.vdr")`

produce the error message:

```
Avisynth open failure:AVIFileSource: couldn't open file 'c:\VHSC\video.vdr'
(C:\VHSC\video.avs, line 1)
(New File, line 1)
```

However, replacing `video.avs` with `homevideo.avi` does display the frames in the AvsP/mod window.

I've seen this similar question [AviSynth can't open my AVI file: "AVISource: Couldn't locate a decompressor for fourcc dvds"](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/24688/avisynth-cant-open-my-avi-file-avisource-couldnt-locate-a-decompressor-for). The virtualdub website < http://www.virtualdub.org/docs_frameserver.html > says "Use the AVISource filter. DirectShowSource is unreliable". I've tried both.

To capture the VHS tapes in VirtualDub I followed a YouTube tutorial, which involved the following steps:

```
Downloaded and install Virtual Dub + Lagarith codec
File > Capture AVI
File > Set capture file[name]
Device > [chose my capture device]
Video > Video source > [chose the source]
Video > Capture filter > PAL_B
Video > Compression > Lagarith
-then in Configure > [mode=]YUY2;
-Checking both Use Multithreading and Prevent Upsampling When Decoding.
Video > Set custom format -- settings: 820 576 YUY2*
(*actually set as UYVY [the default setting] because YUY2 is not compatible with my capture device)
Capture > Settings > 25.0
At the bottom of the capture window -- selected 44.10 kHz, 16 bit, Stereo
Start: Capture > Capture video
End: Capture > Stop capture
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install the frameserver support with auxsetup.exe? You can test if it is working by trying to open your video.vdr with another instance of virtualdub.exe.

From your description it doesn't look you really need the frameserver. You can trim the video with avs itself (e.g. Trim(100,200)), this is more robust and efficient.

Btw did you know there is active avisynth community on forum.doom9.org, forum.videohelp.com